# SOLVED - Kali linux openvas installation fail

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, openvas

I have Kali 2019.4 installed into a Virtualbox machine (4GB, 2-CPU) fully updated and upgraded.

I'm trying to install openvas directly from the Kali repository (apt install openvas) as root, but it is not able to complete the installation process.

After downloaded and unpacked, during the "processing" stage (at around 97%), the installation gives the follow error:

```
<...>
Setting up openvas-manager (7.0.3-1) ...
Creating openvas-scanner's certificate files
ERROR: Failed to create self signed certificate, see /tmp/tmp.dqbpol09MD/openvas-manage-certs.log for details. Aborting.
dpkg: error processing package openvas-manager (--configure):
 installed openvas-manager package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up openvas-cli (1.4.5-2) ...
Setting up openvas-scanner (5.1.3-2) ...
update-rc.d: We have no instructions for the openvas-scanner init script.
update-rc.d: It looks like a non-network service, we enable it.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openvas:
 openvas depends on openvas-manager (>= 7.0.2-4); however:
  Package openvas-manager is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openvas (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.29-2) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (242-7) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.7-3) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.13.1-2+b1) ...
Processing triggers for tex-common (6.12) ...
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... done.
Running mktexlsr /var/lib/texmf ... done.
Building format(s) --all.
    This may take some time... done.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openvas-manager
 openvas
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I check "/tmp/tmp.dqbpol09MD/openvas-manage-certs.log" I have:

```
Generating a 3072 bit RSA private key...
configFileLoad: No such file or directory
Error loading template: /tmp/tmp.dqbpol09MD/caopenvas-cert.cfg
```

checking "/tmp/tmp.dqbpol09MD/caopenvas-cert.cfg", I have:

```
expiration_days = 3652
country = "DE"
locality = "Osnabrueck"
organization = "OpenVAS Users"
unit = "Certificate Authority for kali.' " ' ' "
ca
cert_signing_key
crl_signing_key
```

But here I don't know what to check...

Country and locality are wrong (I'm from Ireland) but maybe they are a default value.

Looks like "unit", "ca", "cert_signing_key" and "crl_signing_key" are not set but maybe at that moment the installation was interrupted.

What do I have to check?
The problem looks like about the cert creation, can I create one before the installation and pass to the installer?

Thanks

EDIT

I reinstalled the machine and this issue doesn't appear anymore.
This time I installed Kali using the official ISO instead of the official vagrant file, maybe this was the issue.

Comment: Looks to me like the Kali openvas packages are busted.  Probably best to send them a bug report.